# PowerShell 7 "Where-Object" and its aliases return nothing

Tags: command-line, powershell

I'll try to make this as concise as possible.

I'm using PowerShell 7.2.0 and cannot get the `where-object` command or its aliases `where` and `?` to work.
What I want is the same functionality as with the `where` command in CMD.

I've tried the command and its aliases, but none of them returns anything. I've confirmed that they're already there (*no aliases need to be set*) with the `get-alias` command.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in **PowerShell** is [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).

Without any parameters, it's the equivalent of `dir` in cmd.

```
PS C:\...\DummyDesktop>gci


    Directory: C:\Users\keith\DummyDesktop


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        10/30/2021   3:51 AM             11 logs.txt
-a----        11/14/2021  11:07 PM           4833 Regex Whitespace Mode.txt
-a----         11/9/2021   4:51 AM           1011 troubleshooting updates.txt
-a----         11/9/2021   2:55 AM            143 Update Error Troubleshooting.url
```

- With no path specified, it uses the current location.
- To include subdirectories of the current location or specifed path, use the `-REcurse` (`-s`) parameter.
- Many simple serachs can be accomplied by using the various parameters of `Get-ChildItem` with literals and/or wildcards.
- More complicated searches may require piping the results of `GetChildItem` to `Where-Object`.
- As you want the fully-qualified path, you'll want the `FullName` property of the FileInfo object returned by `gci`.

```
PS C:\...\Documents>gci ventra*


    Directory: C:\Users\keith\Documents


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          3/2/2016  12:02 PM             27 Ventra.txt
-a----          4/5/2021  11:13 PM            181 Ventra.zip


PS C:\...\Documents>(gci ventra*).FullName
C:\Users\keith\Documents\Ventra.txt
C:\Users\keith\Documents\Ventra.zip
```

THe examples you gave would look like:

```
(gci pyton* -Recurse).FullName
```

- Executed from the root or a folder known to be an ancestor of the location of `python.exe`
- If searching from the root of your system drive, you'll most likely want to use the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` (`-ea silent`) parameter to supress `Access denied` errors.

Comment: This seems much more complex than using `where.exe` as the asker seems to have intended.

Answer (score 0):

The following function worked for me in getting the same functionality that `where` has in `cmd`:

```
function which ($command) {
    Get-Command -Name $command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `where` utility CMD uses (for example, `where.exe python`).